# 新着順 English Meaning

Tags: translation, meaning, nouns

Which is the closest interpretation for「新着順」(しんちゃくじゅん) in English:

"In order of arrival"

"Newest Arrivals"

新着 - 'new arrivals' or 'new acquisitions'

順 - 'order'

Thus, a literal combination of the two leads to 'New arrivals/acquisitions in order'.

This term is used to describe a sorted list of items, thus I believe 'Newest Arrivals' is the smoothest interpretation.

Is my conclusion accurate?

Comment: context please?

Comment: hmm. that helps a little, but I was kind of hoping that you would give some background about why you need to verify this or what you are doing. It might not seem necessary to answer the question, but there are slightly different ways you could say this, and understanding your needs or your concerns could make some difference.  Also members of the website tend to steer clear of questions that look like translation help requests, but context that provides understanding of your efforts makes it easier to answer you meaningfully.

Comment: Oh I see, it's really just out of curiosity.  I will change the question to make it seem less like a translation request shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, 「新着順」 means the same thing as "***reverse chronological order***", in which items are listed from newest to oldest.

Comment: yeah, except you don't see that phrasing on websites where columns of information are labeled... that's why I hesitated to answer... I wanted to know if there was something more "leading" about the situation that could make my answer more relevant.  "New releases" sounded good to me, I just didn't want to commit.

Answer (score 3):

maybe it helps if you split it this way:

新着 - new arrivals

順 - suffix for “[sorting] order”, but  think of it as “first”.

I.e. 新着順 would be “show new arrivals first”.

You can try this approach in e.g. sorting options at NicoVideo:

適合率の高い順 - “high relevance order”, i.e. sort by relevance

新しい番組順 - “new program order”, i.e. sort by newest or show newest first

視聴者が多い順 - big number of viewers order, i.e. sort by number of viewers

コメントが多い順 - big number of comments order, i.e. sort by number of comments